# Dynamic Screen programmatically create View in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

What's the best way to achive this? For example I have a UINavigationBar, UITableView. What should I dynamic put navbar up the screen and tableview below, without hardcode it? Of course i currently have something like: self.view.bounds.origin.y - 20.0, but this is a bad solution i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start reading apples docs about using UIKit. Start [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW1).